# Rails Sample data for each new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, devise

I am currently working on a ToDo app and one of the tasks is to populate each user's account with sample data (a number of tasks, categories and tags), that will be specific for this user (eg their tags won't be visible to anyone else). This should be done during the sign up/ log in process (using Devise) and using seeds.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in `ApplicationController.rb` add this action below where you can check first for user if he already has that data if not then add whatever you want and last line you should redirect user where ever you want.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)


end
```

Comment: This will not work if you plan on using confirmable.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But i think he can check it here if confirmation needed/already used.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the registrations flow by subclassing `Devise::RegistrationsController`.

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      # this block is called after the user is saved
      ["Sweeping", "Vacuuming", "Washing dishes", "Feeding pets"].sample(2).each do |task_name|
        user.tasks.create(name: task_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`super do |user|` can be a bit hard to understand but whats happening here is that we are calling the super method and passing a block. `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` yields the newly created resource:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  # ...
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    # ...
  end
end
```

This lets us tap into the middle of the original method definition so that we don't have to copy-paste the whole thing.

The last step is to configure the routes so that they point to your custom registrations controller:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "my_registrations" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add in my question, that the data needs to be added through seeds. Could that be somehow incorporated in this solution?

Comment: seed.rb is just a Ruby file that gets loaded when you run 'rails db:seed'. In most projects it's just a proceedural mess though and would not really make sense to use it here. A better idea is to put the logic that you use to seed a record in the model or a service object so that you can reuse it.

Comment: I agree, but since this is a requirement for this task, so I need to figure out how to make it work.